# Passing variables to hidden form fields with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hidden-field

Can someone suggest an alternative to the following code for passing hidden form field values?  Thanks in advance for suggestions

```
//Working Fine but breaks some forms
document.write("<INPUT TYPE=\"hidden\" id=\"Field1\" name=\"Field1\" VALUE=\"" + VarXYZ + "\">\r\n");
```

Comment: Do the fields need to be dynamically added? Or do you just want to set the values.

Comment: Please explain what *"breaking a form"* means

Comment: That logic should be on server where you know it will work.

Answer (score 1):

bad aproach. at the first, you should not touch the elements until finish loading all of DOM elements.

if DOM elements are loaded, you do like following.

```
document.getElementById('Field1').value = VarXYZ;
document.getElementById('Field2').value = VarABC;
```

About way to handle document loaded, there is difference in some browsers. So you've better to use jQuery or some useful libraries. Most easy way is:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('Field1').value = VarXYZ;
    document.getElementById('Field2').value = VarABC;
}
```